# Xcode: Set UIView Height and Width to Half of the SuperView's (Master View) Height and Width

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView named `CalendarUIView`. I placed it inside of a view controller called `MainHubViewController`. I want to make it so that the `CalendarUIView`'s height and width are half of the parent's (`MainHubViewController`) height and width. So for example, `MainHubViewController`'s dimensions are  400 by 500. Then I want `CalendarUIVIew`'s dimensions to be 200 by 250.

I put this into my viewdidload method and it didn't work :(

```
self.CalendarUIView.bounds.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0f;
```

Any solutions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change the frame you can do this,

```
view.frame.size = CGSize(width: someW, height: someH)
```

However, you will keep the same origin point so with will be off centre.

So either change the centre point, using .center for the view to match your superview. Or set the frame from the beginning, with takes a CGRect

PS sorry its in Swift the the idea is the same

Answer (score 0):

You should use CGSizeMake

```
self.CalendarUIView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(your width, your height);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the idea

```
//Get the parent size
CGRect *containerFrame = self.MainHubViewController.frame;
float height = containerFrame.size.height;
float width = containerFrame.size.width;


CGRect newFrame = self.CalendarUIView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(width / 2, height / 2);

self.CalendarUIView.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Oddly, when I implement your method, Xcode casts an error: expression is not assignable. :(